# Template rendering is wrong, category shows 2 times

Tags: python, django

So I am trying to render my models in a template but just one tiny thing shows more times than I expect. I just want category name to show one time for many lectures. I just cant figure where to modify the template code.

[image]

```html
<ul>
        {% for a in categories %}
            {% for c in lectures %}
                {% if a == c.course_category %}
                    <li><strong>{{ a.course_category }}</strong></li>
                {% endif %}
                {% if a == c.course_category %}
                    <li>{{ c.lecture_title }}</li>
                    <li>{{ c.content }}</li>
                    {% if c.link %}
                        <li>{{ c.link }}</li>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if c.file %}
                        <li><a href='{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ c.file.url }}'>download</a></li>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            <hr/>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

Comment: This is not the way to iterate over related objects; it's horribly inefficient. Presumably Lecture and Category are related via a foreign key? In which case you should iterate over `a.lecture_set.all`, which directly gives you the lectures within a category.

Comment: I need those ifs, those fields are blank, I want em to show only if populated, but about the fors, how would u change the above code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the `{{ a.course_category }}` out of the inner loop, so that you only display it once for each category.

```
    {% for a in categories %}
        <li><strong>{{ a.course_category }}</strong></li>
        {% for c in lectures %}
            <li>{{ lecture.lecture_title }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

However, it's inefficient to loop through every lecture for every category. Depending on your models, you should be able to do something like:

```
{% for category in categories %}
    <li><strong>{{ category.course_category }}</strong></li>
    {% for lecture in category.lecture_set.all %}
         <li>{{ lecture.lecture_title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Or you might be able to loop through the lectures, and use the `{% ifchanged %}` tag to display the categories.

```
{% for lecture in lectures %}
    {% ifchanged lecture.course_category %}
        <li><strong>{{ lecture.course_category }}</strong></li>
    {% endifchanged %}
    <li>{{ lecture.lecture_title }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Here, the problem is the if one of my categories has no lecture in it, i dont want it to show at all.

Comment: In that case my third example of looping through the lectures should work. You might also be able to use `{% ifchanged %}` in your original code, or `{% if forloop.first %}` in my second example.

Comment: The key thing is to make sure you've got the models and foreign keys correct. If you do that, then looping through them in the templates should be very straight forward. If you haven't, then your templates will be complex.

Comment: "None of those work" isn't enough information for me to help you further. As I said, get the models and foreign key relationships correct first, and then the template should be fairly simple.

Comment: I know how they work, I maybe just lack the knowledge to build the 'if' that I need. Forgot to mention tho, that all my courses share same categories, so basically I would need to find a way that if there is no lecture object, category should not be displayed.

Comment: If your models are set up correctly, then it should be easy to filter categories or lectures in the view.